# adding fields to 2LIS_12_VCITM datasource in ECC

Tags: sap

From what I have read the datasource 2LIS_12_VCITM is built off of the ECC tables LIKP, LIPS, VBUK, and VBUP. I would like to add a couple of fields that are in the LIPS table to this datasource and am wondering on the correct way to do it. Do I simply add the fields to the extract structure of the datasource under the include section for the LIPS table?

Comment: wanted to add tags for "SAP" and "SAP-BW" , but I don't have the points to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways to add fields to a logistics datasource like 2LIS_12_VCITM. If it is a pool field (a field already available in a source table) you can go to t-code LBWE and simply add it to the comm structure of the datasource. Note that before doing this you will need to drain the V3 and V2 update jobs for the datasource.

If the field you want to add is not a pool field then custom code needs to be written to append the field to the datasource or add an exit routine that populates the field when the datasource data is being transferred to BW. An exit routine is less problematic than adding an append structure for the datasource.